# How to rotate mySQL query logs on Windows

Tags: windows, mysql, logging, log-rotation

I'm seeing conflicting (or complementary) answers on how to rotate mySQL logs and want to know if each method is sufficient in itself, or if I need to use a combination of both.

One method, [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584432/log-rotation-mysql-windows-batch), prescribes these steps:

1. `SET` logging `OFF`
2. `RENAME` log file
3. `SET` logging `ON`

Another method, [from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/525788/daily-queries-log-file), gives these steps:

1. `RENAME` the log file
2. `FLUSH LOGS`

[mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html) mentions all these steps but doesn't make clear whether they're different methods of doing the same thing or all necessary steps of the process.  Do I need to `FLUSH LOGS` and `SET` logging on/off, or just do one of the two?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL docs that you referred said "use any of them". But the following

> FLUSH LOGS supports optional modifiers to enable selective flushing of individual logs (for example, FLUSH BINARY LOGS).
>
> A log-flushing operation does the following:
>
> - If general query logging or slow query logging to a log file is enabled, the server closes and reopens the general query log file or slow query log file.
> - If binary logging is enabled, the server closes the current binary log file and opens a new log file with the next sequence number.
> - If the server was started with the --log-error option to cause the error log to be written to a file, the server closes and reopens the log file.

does not work on Windows for opened files (see [How can I rename files and folders in Windows that are in use?](https://superuser.com/questions/54193/how-can-i-rename-files-and-folders-in-windows-that-are-in-use), [Renaming an open file](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?522443-Renaming-an-open-file)).

Also, the docs says

> `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'OFF'; ...`
>
> This method works on any platform